# With JQuery, Can I display the ids and update them in drag and sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JQuery Drag and sort.

for example

```
     1) Title
     2) Title
     3) Title
```

And I need to be able to update the number when you sort them. 
so if you move 1 to 3 they will update 1 to be 3, 2 to be 1 and 3 to be 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed your draggable elements have the class `draggable` you should call something like this  on dragstop (I think the event is called `stop` in jQuery UI)

```
$(".draggable").each(function(i){
   $(this).html(i+1);
});
```

Comment: How do I display that in the HTML
<javascript print(i)>

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean with `<javascript print(i)>`

Comment: How do I get it to reder this. Is that just going to put a 1 2 or a 3 in the li by default?

Comment: the `i` is the index of the jQuery each. So the first element found is index 0, the second index 1, etc. So in the example it just outputs a number in the html of the current element `$(this)` which would be the draggable itself. If you want to output a different string you could add something to the i like `$(this).html("element no. "+(i+1))` or you could define a different tag say a span inside of the draggable container and then output the number in there - e.g. `$(this).find(".myspan").html(i+1)`

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe I am implementing it wrong or my version of jquery is newer or somehthing.

Comment: Can you  post your on jsfiddle?